# ADO.NET DAL and BLL

Tags: c#

***I have two classes `SqlHelper` and `DishesTypes` there are used in a DAL project***

```cs
public class SqlHelper
{ 
    public static SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(string procedure, 
        params SqlParameter[] commandParameters) 
    {             
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))       
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(procedure, _connection)) 
        {                    
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddRange(commandParameters);
            return command.ExecuteReader();                                 
        }    
    }

    public class DishesTypes 
    {
        public static SqlDataReader DishesTypesSelectAll() 
        {
            return SqlHelper.ExecuteReader("DishesTypesSelectAllRows"); //name of procedure
        }
    }
```

***And I have class `DishedTypes` that used in a BLL project like this***

```cs
public class DishesTypes
{
    public int DishTypeId { get; set; }
    public string DishType { get; set; }

    public static List<DishesTypes> DishesTypesSelectAll()
    {
        IDataReader dr = DataAccessLayer.DishesTypes.DishesTypesSelectAll();          

        List<DishesTypes> dishesTypesList = new List<DishesTypes>();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            DishesTypes myDishesTypes = new DishesTypes
            {
                DishTypeId = (int)dr["DishTypeId"],
                DishType = (string)dr["DishType"]
            };
            dishesTypesList.Add(myDishesTypes);
        }
        return dishesTypesList;
    }
}
```

Problems starts here `while (dr.Read())`,The reason, the connection to this point has already closed and it is necessary to reconnect how best to change the implementation of classes adhering layers DAL and BLL, to work?

Comment: You should not put into a `using` statement something that you return. It will be disposed or closed at some point outside of the callers control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to roll your own, something like this is better:

```
public class DataQuery
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DataQuery(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>(string procedure,
        Func<IDataRecord, T> entityCreator,
        params SqlParameter[] commandParameters
        )
    {
        var result = new List<T>();
        using (var connection = CreateConnection())
        using (var command = CreateCommand(procedure, connection, commandParameters))
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            result.Add(entityCreator(reader));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private SqlConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }

    private static DbCommand CreateCommand(string procedure, 
        SqlConnection connection, SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand(procedure, connection)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };
        command.Parameters.AddRange(commandParameters);
        return command;
    }
}
```

Which you would call like this:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"]
    .ConnectionString;

var query = new DataQuery(connectionString);
Func<IDataRecord, DishesTypes> creator = dr => 
    new DishesTypes
    {
        DishTypeId = (int)dr["DishTypeId"],
        DishType = (string)dr["DishType"]
    };

var results = query.GetList("DishesTypesSelectAllRows", creator);
```

---

Otherwise, which I recommend, have a look at [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net).

Dapper would allow you to simply do:

```
var results = connection.Query<DishesTypes>("DishesTypesSelectAllRows", 
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `using` statement is closing your connection, so you cannot expect to return a useable `IDataReader`. Second, your connection is never opened, so you would not get a result, anyway. Having said that, if your dataset will always be small enough to fit in memory, you could use something like what I have done below. This should have minimal impact on your code.

```
    public class SqlHelper
    {
        public static IDataReader ExecuteReader(string procedure, params SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(procedure, connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.AddRange(commandParameters);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt.CreateDataReader();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class DishesTypes
    {
        public static IDataReader DishesTypesSelectAll()
        {
            return SqlHelper.ExecuteReader("DishesTypesSelectAllRows");//name of procedure
        }

    }
```